# How to get data from firebase database using firebase cloud function http trigger

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

Hi I want to fetch data from firebase database using firebase cloud function http trigger. Is it possible using functions.database.ref?

```
var functions = require('firebase-functions');
var cors = require("cors");
var express = require('express');
var http = require('http');

const app = express()
//~ app.use(cors({ origin: true }))
app.get("/", (request, response) => {
  response.send("Hello from Express on Firebase with CORS!")
})
app.get("/:id", (request, response) => {
     functions.database.ref('/Users/'+request.params.id)
})

    exports.httpFunction = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

thanks

Comment: Your question is too broad. Please add some code if you tried something. If you didn't please do a google search and read some tutorials about firebase and cloud functions. Firebase doc is pretty good for explaining things. Check [ask] to learn about good questions.

Comment: please check my code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Firebase Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/) to make database manipulations inside Cloud Functions.

Rather than using

```
functions.database.ref()
```

You can use

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

// inside your triggered function
admin.database().ref('path/to/your/ref').on('value').then((snapshot) => { ... })
```

Comment: @harry please update your question with what you done and the complete error you get.